# Factor $ x^3-3x^2-4x+12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I go about factoring this problem?

What is the best method? I can not factor out an $x$ since the $12$ does not have a variable. I usually use the Criss Cross method.

Comment: Try plugging in some small integers to see if there is one that results in $0$, then that is one of your factors

Comment: Elaborate on "Criss Cross" and you should consider marking best answers on your previous questions.

Comment: Yes, for instance $x=2$.

Comment: If the polynomial factors in rationals it factors in integers(rational root theorem) also root divides $a_0$ of polynomial so root divides $12$ only choices are $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm6,\pm12$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using factoring by grouping:

$x^3−3x^2−4x+12=x^2(x-3)-4(x-3)=(x^2-4)(x-3)$

You can expand further by using the difference of squares $x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)$.

The factored expression then becomes $(x-2)(x+2)(x-3)$.

Comment: You can also factor $x^2-4$.

Comment: (x^2-4)(x-3). Is that the answer?

Comment: (x-2)(x+2)(x-3)

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. Both factored forms are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping to get $(x^2-4)(x-3)$ and then don't forget to factor $x^2-4$ as $(x+2)(x-2)$.